# Why pullback in Set is defined through equality $f(a) = g(b)$

Tags: category-theory, pullback

There's a recurring example of a pullback in **Set** category, mentioned at least [on Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pullback_(category_theory)#Sets), [here](https://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/pullback#in_category_theory), and in some book I've read.

It is: take sets $A$, $B$, $Z$, and functions $f: A → Z$ and $g: B → Z$. The pullback $Q = A×_Z B$ then defined to be $\{(a,b) ∈ A×B | f(a) = g(b)\}$.

The problem is that the categorical definition says nothing about equality, so I can take any single pair $(a,b) ∈ A×B$, with injections to $A$ and $B$.

$$ \begin{array}{}
\begin{align} & \quad \; \; (a,b) \\ 
& \; \, \swarrow \quad \quad \searrow \\
& A  \quad \quad \quad \; \; B \\
& _f\searrow \quad \quad \swarrow _g \\
& \quad \quad Z \end{align}
\end{array} $$

There is a function $Q → (a,b)$, and an injection $(a,b) → Q$, thus they're both satisfying to the universal property, and $(a,b)$ is a pullback too.

Is my reasoning correct, and the recurring example is just a special case of a pullback in **Set** *(and authors not mention it as such just to confuse everyone)*, or do I miss something important?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The functions between $Q$ and $(a,b)$ aren't isomorphisms in most cases, so actually $(a,b)$ doesn't satisfy the universal property. In other words: you need there to be a unique function from $(a,b)$ to $Q$ making everything commute, which isn't generally true, and a unique function in the other direction making everything commute, but generally your function $Q\to (a,b)$ won't actually do that.

Comment: Ah, *the unique function*, that is! Thank you!

Comment: I just saw a subtlety I don't understand though. $Q$ do have the unique function to the pair $(a,b)$, it's just a mapping of all pairs in $Q$ to $(a,b)$. But on the other hands, there're many injections $(a,b) → Q$. So by virtue of having unique incoming arrow, $(a,b)$ should be the pullback! *(I'm assuming the Eric's 1-st point holds, i.e. I'm talking just about uniqueness)*.

Comment: Yeah, if the unique arrow to $(a,b)$ actually made the square commute, then $(a,b)$ would be the pullback. The two conditions in the definition pull in opposite directions: that there exists an arrow making the square commute suggests the pullback should be big. But that it be unique suggests the opposite. Thus the pullback sits at some nicely balanced size in between $A\times B$, the biggest possibility, and $\{\}$, the smallest, and in some cases it might indeed be your $(a,b)$.

Answer (score 5):

Equality *is* mentioned in the definition of the pullback, in the key assumption that your diagrams must commute.  The definition of a pullback is:

> A diagram $A\stackrel{p}\leftarrow C\stackrel{q}\to B$ is a pullback of $A\stackrel{f}\to Z\stackrel{g}\leftarrow B$ if:
>
> 1. $fp=gq$ and
> 2. Given any diagram $A\stackrel{r}\leftarrow D\stackrel{s}\to B$ such that $fr=gs$ there is a unique map $u:D\to C$ such that $pu=r$ and $qu=s$.

In particular, the condition that $fp=gq$ immediately rules out an arbitrary singleton $\{(a,b)\}$ being the pullback in general.  Indeed, if you were to take $\{(a,b)\}$ to be the pullback with $p$ and $q$ the projections, then $f(p(a,b))=f(a)$ and $g(q(a,b))=g(b)$, so you need $f(a)=g(b)$ to be true.

So this is where the equality $f(a)=g(b)$ comes from.  But you still can't just pick a single pair $(a,b)$ such that $f(a)=g(b)$ is true and conclude that $\{(a,b)\}$ is the pullback, since you still need condition (2) to be true.  In particular, if you take $D$ to be an arbitrary singleton $\{(a,b)\}$ such that $f(a)=g(b)$, the existence and uniqueness of the map $u$ tells you that $C$ must contain exactly one point corresponding to $(a,b)$.  And in order for $fp=gq$ to be true, every point of $C$ must correspond to a pair $(a,b)$ such that $f(a)=g(b)$.  So $C$ must be in bijection with the set of all pairs $(a,b)$ such that $f(a)=g(b)$.  (To make this a formal proof, you need to precisely say what "correspond" means: an element $c\in C$ "corresponds" to $(a,b)\in A\times B$ if $p(c)=a$ and $q(c)=b$.)

Comment: Sorry, but I looked both in Wikipedia and in the "definition" paragraph [here](https://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/pullback#definition), and I didn't see the $fp = gq$ being part of the definition. That is, it's mentioned in examples, such as the one I asked about, but I didn't see it in the definition.

Comment: Those equations are what it means when the definitions say certain diagrams "commute" or are "commutative".  A diagram commutes if any two paths from one object to another are equal when you compose the maps along them.  So saying the square made up of $f$, $p$, $g$, and $q$ commutes says that the two paths from $C$ to $Z$, namely $fp$ and $gq$, must be equal.